# 404 Not Found in Wso2apimanager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I created an api in wso2apimanager 1.7 and subscribed the created api through creating an application. But when i call the api using a REST client (postman) i'm getting 404 Not Found error.

cURL request

```
curl -X GET -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Authorization: Bearer f3afa04c46c95461ff2df4d037e9b2f" -H "Postman-Token: 8cb664dd-76ec-5ee1-40ee-ff27a1ce1942" "http://localhost:8280/test/path/V1/"
```

Response is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

below is my api definition xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
     name="admin--TestingAPI"
     context="/test/path"
     version="V1"
     version-type="url">
   <resource methods="POST GET OPTIONS DELETE PUT"
             url-mapping="/*"
             faultSequence="fault">
      <inSequence>
         <send>
            <endpoint name="admin--TestingAPI_APIproductionEndpoint_0">
               <http uri-template="http://httpbin.org/ip"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
   <handlers>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler"/>
   </handlers>
</api>
```

Comment: plase share you api definition xml.

Comment: questing is edited. thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you create this API? Why can't I see other default handlers?

Comment: I created that api by using publisher. Nothing was edited manually. I created several apis and they contains those default handlers. I deleted the api and created a new one again. now works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your backend service. It gives 404 when you try `http://httpbin.org/ip/` instead of `http://httpbin.org/ip`. (note the slash at the end)

So if you send your request to below URL, it should work I think.

```
http://localhost:8280/test/path/V1
```

Comment: yes. something was wrong with the api. Thanks. it worked for another api.

Comment: it's the ending `/`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not used API Context and/or its resource name, Please give a try with that otherwise, please provide your API Definition with back-end API details for further help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/Create+and+Publish+an+API) tutorial to get an idea how to create an API. It is for APIM 2.0.0 but the skills are transferable.